# Gerrit : Authentication unavailable at this time

Tags: gerrit

I have issue in logging in gerrit server and it prompts "Authentication unavailable at this time". I tried restarting the gerrit service but when it was about to start the service it shown the following message.

[image]

This is not the main server but the mirror server and login works fine with the main gerrit server.

Could anyone help in resolving this issue (login issue)? Or do I need to change anything in ldap settings in gerrit.config file.

Comment: The issue is resolved after tried restarting the gerrit server nearly 5 times, but I am not sure whether it is resolved because of restart or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gerrit setup has two separate problems:

1. Authentication unavailable at this time: this means that Gerrit wasn't able to authenticate with your LDAP server and thus cannot search and authenticate any account
2. Could not adjust the Gerrit process scoring for the OOM killer: this means that you are not running `gerrit.sh` as root and thus you don't have permission to tune the /proc// settings and potentially the kernel could kill the Gerrit JVM without notice.

For solving 1. just check your LDAP settings in gerrit.config against your LDAP credentials.

For solving 2. just run gerrit.sh as `root`. The shell script will then impersonate the gerrit user before running the JVM.

HTH

Luca.